# Execute a command as sudo from within a rake task?

Tags: ruby, rake, sudo

Other than hard-coding "sudo" into the exec/system argument string, is there a flag in Rake that specifies that a command needs to be executed with root privileges, and will prompt for a password if needed?  Like how Babushka has a `:sudo => true` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't know if there's a Rake option for this (but I suppose there isn't). you can easyly do it by checking user's privileges. check this answer:

[On Unix, find if user who executed the program is root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641449/ruby-in-unix-find-if-user-who-executed-the-program-is-root)

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much.  It actually turns out `sudo` wouldn't do and I need to use `rvmsudo` instead.  But the result is the same.  It would be nice if Rake provided a framework for this, as it's probably quite common :)